# And or Logic filter out dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
STARTDATE               ENDDATE                 COMPANYID   TIMESERIESREFRECID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000 OK          105637207641
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 OK          105637207641
```

> **NB:** Don't mind the join names and aliases, there are many other tables but not necessary for your information
>
> **NB2:** 1900-01-01 Means that it's valid for this time and forward (so actually it should be 9999-12-31 if it should be 100 percent right. But hope you get the idea.

And I have a SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT E.STARTDATE,e.ENDDATE, c.COMPANYID, a.TIMESERIESREFRECID 
FROM [stg].[EMS_TimeSeriesValues] a WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join [stg].ContractPart e WITH (NOLOCK)  

on d.DATAAREAID = e.DATAAREAID and d.CONTRACTNUM = e.CONTRACTNUM 
and (e.ENDDATE > GETDATE() or  e.ENDDATE = '1900-01-01')
```

What I want is, I only want the Row, that is currently valid. That means I want the row where enddate is still not met.

I've tried this:

```
and (e.ENDDATE > GETDATE() and e.StartDate < getdate() or  e.ENDDATE = '1900-01-01')
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried with different parentheses but I can't seem to get it right.

So desired result for now should be:

```
 STARTDATE               ENDDATE                    COMPANYID   TIMESERIESREFRECID
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-12-31 00:00:00.000    OK          105637207641
```

And when we are in year 2019, I of course only want this row:

```
 STARTDATE               ENDDATE                COMPANYID   TIMESERIESREFRECID
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000    OK          105637207641
```

Comment: think your missing a paren:
and 
(e.ENDDATE > GETDATE() and e.StartDate < getdate())
OR ( e.ENDDATE = '1900-01-01')  The OR needs to be seperated by parens

Comment: The `or` is processed last so it *wins*

Comment: Tip: `GetDate()` is treated a bit oddly in queries. Each _instance_ will have a constant value within a query. For example `select GetDate() as D1, GetDate() as D2 from SomeTable` may return two different values for the two columns, but they will not vary from one row to the next. When using multiple calls to `GetDate()`, whether in a single statement or multiple statements, one may avoid interesting surprises by getting a single value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and use `@Now` as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `enddate` and `startdate` are `datetime`, this should get you the desired results:

```
SELECT e.STARTDATE, e.ENDDATE, c.COMPANYID, a.TIMESERIESREFRECID 
FROM [stg].[EMS_TimeSeriesValues] AS a 
inner join [stg].ContractPart AS e 
ON d.DATAAREAID = e.DATAAREAID 
AND d.CONTRACTNUM = e.CONTRACTNUM 
WHERE e.STARTDATE < GETDATE()
AND (e.ENDDATE > GETDATE() OR e.ENDDATE = '1900-01-01T00:00:00')
```

Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) to see why I've removed your `NOLOCK` hints.

P.S
`EndDate` should be a future date or null. I like to use either `9999-12-31` or [`2525-01-01`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N03Uoj6p9QA) (even if my applications will last that long, it's going to be [SEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_else%27s_problem))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nolock is used due too business requirements. All tables are trigger updated/inserted every 2 minutes. And yes. Future date should be 9999 i agree.

Comment: It looks like its correct. I wrote it in my join expression though. Thanks

Comment: I would advise against that. The `on` clause should handle only what's relevant to the `join`. The conditions that handles only  a single table in an inner join should be written in the `where` clause. It should have no effect performance-wise, but it's much more readable that way.

Comment: Thank you, ill take that into consideration!